# calling a custom javascript function from js.haml

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have defined a javascript function for manipulating a table using dataTables. i have provided custom column definitions for the table as

```
setTableStyle = -> 
  columnDefs = [ { "bSearchable": true, "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] }, { "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 4 ] } ]

  $('#agents_list, #search_list').dataTable
    'bFilter': false
    'bAutoWidth': false
    'aaSorting': [[ 3, 'desc' ]]
    'bPaginate': false
    'aoColumnDefs': columnDefs
```

i m ajax polling for changes in agents n using 'fnDraw' to redraw the table in the js.haml file. the js.haml code is as

```
$('#agents_list').replaceWith("#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'agents_table', locals: {agents: @agents, id: 'agents_list'})}");
var columnDefs = [{"bSearchable": true, "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [0, 1, 2, 3] }, {"bSortable": false,"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [4]}];
var oTable = $('#agents_list').dataTable({ 'bFilter': false, 'bAutoWidth': false, 'aaSorting': [[3, 'desc']], 'bPaginate': false, 'aoColumnDefs': columnDefs});
oTable.fnDraw();
```

i cant call the 'setTableStyle' from the js.haml hence i have to repeat the code. how do i avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare the function as global in controller_name.js.coffee file. the coffeescript code is as

```
@setTableStyles ->
  #code goes here.
```

this function can be called from anywhere. In js.haml do

```
setTableStyles();
```